# Makefile execution: permission denied

Tags: go, makefile, fedora

I've got a quite strange problem with golang and Makefile (on Fedora 33).
My Makefile contains:

```
run:
  go run main.go
```

which should only print "Hello" to the console. When I run `make run` I get this error:

```
go run main.go
make: go: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:5: run] Error 127
```

However, if I change my Makefile to

```
  run:
    /usr/bin/go run main.go
```

it works just fine!

**INFO**

Outputs of:

```
$ which go
/usr/bin/go

$ go version
go version go1.15.5 linux/amd64

$ uname -a 
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.9.10-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 23 18:12:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone help me with this? If you need more info please tell me!

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Console

```
$ echo ${PATH}
/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/olena/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

Output of `make`

```
echo /usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/olena/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/olena/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
go run main.go
make: go: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:6: run] Error 127
```

In `/usr/bin`

```
$ ll | grep go
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root 20 Nov 14 09:32 go -> /etc/alternatives/go
```

In `/etc/alternatives`

```
$ ll | grep go
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Nov 29 15:16 go -> /usr/lib/golang/bin/go
```

Comment: Try `make -d` to see more information. Could be an issue with the path env variable so that `make` is not using /usr/bin/go.  To check add `echo ${PATH}` in your run target.  If not the same, `make -e` to give preference to your shell env variables.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Don't use go run with filename arguments.

Comment: See clarifications above. Seems not to be a path error?

Answer (score 6):

I ran to the same issue as yours and finally figured out what was wrong with mine.  Maybe this works for you, especially if you use zsh with omz.

In my case, one of the locations defined in $PATH contains a folder named go.  That location came before where `go` binary was in.  Once I put that location to be after the binary location, everything just worked.

I believe maybe it has something to do with omz and how its shell functions allow you to go into a folder.

Comment: This answer does not make sense. If you have folder /tmp/go and $PATH="/tmp/go:$PATH", go just works.

Comment: It worked for me like you mentioned in bash, but it didn't work when using make.

Comment: It's really strange that this is causing make to fail but I observe the same behaviour with make 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can add '@' before command to hide output in terminal

```
run:
    @/usr/bin/go run main.go
```

it outputs only 'Hello'

Comment: I'm not following why you think `@` will help.  The problem is not that the `go` command is printed to `make`'s output, but rather that it *fails* (and in fact does not output "Hello").